# What exactly is sun.jnu.encoding?

Tags: java, encoding

What is the purpose of the system property `sun.jnu.encoding`? Various fragments on the web set or report it, but I can't find a definition.

Answer (score 32):

see http://happygiraffe.net/blog/2009/09/24/java-platform-encoding/

This link describes the usage of the `sun.jnu.encoding` property for using the correct encoding when parsing values passed via the commandline, something that setting the `file.encoding` property doesn't influence.

Comment: Archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20200202094903/http://happygiraffe.net/blog/2009/09/24/java-platform-encoding/

Answer (score 16):

I did some investigation on encoding and as per my analysis

1. sun.jnu.encoding affects the creation of file name (this possibly gets set by LANG on unix before starting java)
2. file.encoding affects the content of a file

Comment: sun.jnu.encoding is referenced in several places in the OpenJDK 8 sources. It does seem related to the encoding of pathnames. From my experiments, setting it with `-D` was ineffective; I had to actually configure the right locale for the whole system and process, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553499/12916.

Answer (score 9):

I tried to centralize all the information provided in the answers here and elsewhere on the Web, in order to make the most complete answer possible.

As other comments have noted, there are actually two properties that affect the chosen encoding on the JVM:

- `sun.jnu.encoding`, also known as the "platform encoding" or "JNU encoding", is an undocumented, [internal](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html) property that holds the name of the encoding to use for interacting with the platform (e.g. [file paths](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8187041) and [JNI C String to Java String conversions](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/79d12507b373f4d46702cd606eda8590c1d03318/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/jni_util.c#L794-L810) — maybe also [command-line arguments, main classes and environment variables](https://web.archive.org/web/20200202094903/http://happygiraffe.net/blog/2009/09/24/java-platform-encoding/), but I wasn't able to verify this claim).
  ​
  On [MacOS](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/a4ab61339bbd4a39f806c514039e2dd47dcb4169/src/java.base/unix/native/libjava/java_props_md.c#L452-L456), this is always UTF-8, on [Linux](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/a4ab61339bbd4a39f806c514039e2dd47dcb4169/src/java.base/unix/native/libjava/java_props_md.c#L455) it's always the same as `file.encoding` (unless `file.encoding` is overriden, in which case I do not know what happens), and on [Windows](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/a4ab61339bbd4a39f806c514039e2dd47dcb4169/src/java.base/windows/native/libjava/java_props_md.c#L677-L688) it can vary.
- `file.encoding`, also known as the "default charset" or "user encoding", is mainly used to determine the charset for encoding/decoding file *contents*. This is the charset that `java.nio.charsets.Charset.defaultCharset()` returns. Note that the value in `file.encoding` is used by many JDK APIs as the default encoding, but can be overridden by providing an explicit `Charset` or a charset name in the call to the JDK method.

These properties are [determined dynamically when the JVM starts](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8187041) (though this is not the case for GraalVM Native Image, which [sets them at build time](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2492) as of this writing).

Finally, as [this draft JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8187041) states:

> The value of these system properties can be overridden on the command line although doing so has never been supported.

Comment: I wasn't able to find what the "jnu" in `sun.jnu.encoding` is, but if anyone knows, I'm curious about it!

Comment: `JNU_` is the prefix of internally used functions or macros in the JVM native code. According to the only (old) document I found, “JNU” stands for “JNI utilities”.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this value represents the system encoding, which may be different from the user encoding ("file.encoding") on some platforms. The "sun" prefix makes me suspect that this is an implementation detail specific to the Sun JRE (a quick look at an IBM 1.4 VM shows an "ibm.system.encoding" system property). I have no idea on how this might be used internally - though I'm sure a quick look through the [source](http://download.java.net/jdk7/) would yield some clues.