# How to define charset based on the operating system?

Tags: java, character-encoding

For example:

In russian language, has the charset of Koi8-r and cp866. In case of linux and unix the charset koi8-r works fine. But in case of windows and dos cp866 works fine. Is there any way to define the charset correctly based on platform. I want this to be done for all languages. Please help thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please explain your problem more thoroughly. What is the client/server setup. What protocols are you using. You cannot solve the problem like you explain below, but maybe we can give you some hints to a better solution if we have more information available.

Comment: Koi8-r is working fine in Windows.

Comment: What about windows-1251?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My need is based on client and server operation. From the client they
> request some files. from the request i have to get the platform, based
> on that i have to encode the filename in server and return the
> reponse. so server will always in the same platform. Based on client
> platform, i have to rturn response.

You seem to be under the impression that client/server protocols are supposed to decide their character encoding based on the client's OS and locale.  That is not required.  For example, the [HTTP Accept-Charset header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.2) is allowed to be ignored.  [What *is* required](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2277#section-3.1) (at least for IETF protocols) is the ability to use UTF-8, and to declare the encoding (e.g., `Content-Type: text/html; charset=KOI8-R`).

Unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise, I'd recommend sending your response in UTF-8.  [That's what ⅔ of the Web does.](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/character_encoding/all)

The remaining question is how to determine the file encoding on the server.  An approach that works most of the time is:

1. If it validates as UTF-8, then assume it *is* UTF-8.
2. Otherwise, assume the platform's default encoding (e.g., `java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset().name()` as recommended by Martin).

(If desired, you can also add detect for UTF-32 (with or without BOM) and/or UTF-16 (with BOM).)

Answer (score 1):

It would be very bad to determine the charset based solely on the type of operating system. It is however very easy to determine the character set at runtime. On Unix f.ex. we have the `$LC_*` class of environment variables. In Java it is even easier.

A quick search reveals this page as an example: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0505.html

What you want is probably the `java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset().name()` value.

Comment: My need is based on client and server operation. From the client they request some files. from the request i have to get the platform, based on that i have to encode the filename in server and return the reponse. so server will always in the same platform. Based on client platform, i have to rturn response.

Comment: Protocols like HTTP usually include an encoding header.

Comment: If you use a proprietary protocol, you should handle the encoding at that level. Either include a header (like HTTP) or decide on a standard encoding for transfers!

Comment: The user can select any language on the client side. Based on that i have to change the encoding. Is there any avaliable list that define proper charset based on the platform for all charsets. like this one. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html

Comment: Can you just use UTF-8 for everything when everything fails?

Comment: @user828234: No, you **cannot** determine charset based solely on the type of platform. Any platform can have **any** encoding!

Comment: Is there manually available list for my reference? based on i put condition in the code.

Comment: If the client is in your control (i.e. you have the source, can compile, etc.) why not encode the data to a predetermined charset before sending?

Comment: @user828234: Sorry, but no. I do not think a list like that exists.

Comment: @user828234: There are ways to automatically determine data encoding, but the are (in my experience) messy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499010/java-how-to-determine-the-correct-charset-encoding-of-a-stream

Answer (score -1):

Use `sun.jnu.encoding` system property

See [What exactly is sun.jnu.encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066845/what-exactly-is-sun-jnu-encoding)

Comment: @Martin Olsen Thanks, I didn't explain further... Encoding is always platform-dependent :)

Comment: More: [http://happygiraffe.net/blog/2009/09/24/java-platform-encoding/](http://happygiraffe.net/blog/2009/09/24/java-platform-encoding/)