# How can I Enable Unaccent for postgres in Docker-Compose?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I need to enable the accents for postgreSQL. This is my `docker-compose.yml`, but it doesn't work. Any tips? Thank you.

```
db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - 5432
  environment:
    DB_UNACCENT: true
mailcatcher:
  image: aboutsource/mailcatcher
  ports:
    - "1080:1080"
web:
  build: .
  command: passenger start --port 3000
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  environment:
   - RAILS_ENV=development
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
    - "25:25"
    - "587:587"
  links:
    - db
    - mailcatcher
```

Answer (score -3):

See my previous answer on that topic [How to set the locale inside a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405902/how-to-set-the-locale-inside-a-docker-container/28406007#28406007)

Adapt it with the correct locale for your need.

Comment: Your linked answer is about the `ENV` keyword in a `Dockerfile`. But this is about `docker-compose.yml` files.