# uWSGI / Emperor: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

i have big problem with encoding on uwsgi/emeror/nginx server.
My app is developed to batch excel files processing.

I use latest version flask and flask-extensions and use flask-excel.

My app runs on Digital Ocean / Ubuntu server and my config files are:

/etc/init/uwsgi.conf

```
description "uWSGI"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn

env UWSGI=/home/lukas/www/abissk/venv/bin/uwsgi
env LOGTO=/home/lukas/logs/abissk/emperor.log
exec $UWSGI --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --die-on-term --uid www-data --gid www-data --logto $LOGTO
```

/etc/uwsgi/vassals/abissk_uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python
#pcre = True

#application's base folder
base = /home/lukas/www/abissk/

#enable-threads = true

#python module to import
app = wsgi
module = %(app) 

home = %(base)venv
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /home/lukas/www/abissk/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket = 644

#the variable that holds a flask application inside the module imported at line #6
callable = app

#location of log files
logto = /home/lukas/logs/abissk/%n.log
```

/home/lukas/www/abissk/wsgi.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 *-*
from app.app import create_app
from app.settings import ProdConfig

app = create_app(config_object=ProdConfig)
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/abissk_nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name benela.abis.sk; 
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location / { try_files $uri @yourapplication; }
    location @yourapplication {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/lukas/www/abissk/abissk_uwsgi.sock;
    }

}
```

and here is my problem:
When start application with command:

```
 ~/www/abissk/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/vassals/abissk_uwsgi.ini
```

and upload excel files works all great BUT

when start same aplication with totaly same config files (in /etc/init/uwsgi.conf) with emperor, application works fine, but when upload excel file to batch processing, i see only message: "502 Bad Gateway" and in my log is:

```
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfd' in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)
```

i was try install uwsgi with apt-get / pip3 install and scenario is same: when run app directly without emperor, works all fine; when run app with emperor (with same configuration), every upload excel file to my app ends with crash :/

Thanks for any answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add the following lines to your abissk_uwsgi.ini file to enforce uwsgi to use UTF-8.

```
env LANG=en_US.utf8
env LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
env LC_LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks.  I needed to make it env = LANG=en_US.utf8 as suggested

Comment: For anyone using Docker, try `C.UTF-8` instead. Or you might need to install the locales first. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41648500/336694

Comment: Added `env = PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` as well

Answer (score 5):

Add to `uwsgi.ini`:

```
env = LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Only this format helped for me

Comment: This can be set to any of the UTF-8 encodings and is probably best set to whatever the system default locale is set to. For example I used `env = LANG=en_AU.UTF8` as this is what my system default locale is set to in `/etc/default/locale`

Answer (score 1):

for Russian language add this in uwsgi.ini

```
env = LANG=ru_RU.utf8
env = LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
env = LC_LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the variables `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, `LC_LANG` helped me.

I fixed the bug only adding this to the uwsgi.ini:

`env = PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`