# uWSGI encode error 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, uwsgi

I have already tried everything suggested at [uWSGI / Emperor: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452529/uwsgi-emperor-unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character)
but nothing worked.

here is my ini file

```
[uwsgi]
# -------------
# Settings:
# key = value
# Comments >> #
# -------------

env LANG=en_US.utf8
env LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
env LC_LANG=en_US.UTF-8
env = PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8

# socket = [addr:port]
http = 127.0.0.1:8000


# WSGI module and callable
# module = [wsgi_module_name]:[application_callable_name]
module = church.wsgi

# master = [master process (true of false)]
master = true

static-map = /static=/home/....church/static 

# processes = [number of processes]
processes = 5


..
```

Basically I have a simple django app fetching stocks names with unicode characters like öé etc.
the Django development server works find and return no error. In production  it returns

```
"  'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)"
```

so parsing fails and date is not added to the db.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas excuse my ignorance but this is the full error I receive from uwsgi. How do I get the traceback ?

Comment: @furas just as a P.S. if you think that my question is not complete there is need to follow all my posts to comment. I am confident that this is the only error that uwsgi gives me -- which is clearly because is buggy in year 2020 utf encoding should be a given not something to debug - Gunicorn works fine out of the box.

Comment: I see so many questions every day so I don't rememer other your questions.