# How to add locale in docker container

Tags: docker, containers, locale

I want to add locale into my container.

When I'm root on my container, and I do `locale -a`, I have this :

```
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

I tried to add locale with this : `locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8`. After I restarted container.

But when I do `locale -a`, I don't have `fr_FR.uft8`...

But I don't understant when I exit to container an do `locale -a`, I have fr_FR.utf8!

How can I add locale into my container?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405902/how-to-set-the-locale-inside-a-docker-container/28406007#28406007. ?

Comment: By the way, you need to `docker commit` in order to save your changes