# running node.js in docker calling a shell script , gibberish errors

Tags: node.js, docker, imagemagick

I am running nodejs app on my mac. Nodejs code is calling a shell script to executive imagemagick

```
$baseDir/ffmpeg -i $FileName -vf scale=$scale:-1 -r $frate  $folderName/%04d.png
```

it works good.

After I put everything in a docker container, nodejs app is running fine and can be accessible same as before through localhost:3000. However, in side of it, Calling the same shell script outputs the errors below,

```
ctv_processor/ffmpeg: 1: ctv_processor/ffmpeg: �����@
                                                     ��!H__PAGEZERO�__TEXT�D�__text__TEXT: not found
ctv_processor/ffmpeg: 2: ctv_processor/ffmpeg: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Any clue what those gibberish outputs are?

Regards
Hammer

**Update**

I change my dockerfile to use locale-gen successfully,

```
FROM node:4-onbuild


# Set the locale
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update
RUN apt-get install locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
RUN dpkg-reconfigure locales
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

However, when I bash into my container, it gives me

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
root@0a2290d00a2e:/usr/src/ctv_server_app# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

So, still gibberish :( Any idea?

Comment: did you install some locales in your docker container? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405902/how-to-set-the-locale-inside-a-docker-container/28406007#28406007

Comment: I add the locale-gen, but run into error "/bin/sh: 1: locale-gen: not found"

Comment: In your Dockerfile, you use `FROM` what OS?

Comment: tried node:argon and node:4-onbuild

Comment: I can install the locale-gen with the dockerfile updated in my questions. However, when i bash into the container, it gives me the error (pls refer to the update on the questions)

Comment: btw, I get the locale right, but problem is still there.

Comment: when you are still inside your container, post `more /etc/default/locale`