# Debian Jessie - font € sign is rendered as fi ligature

Tags: node.js, docker, fonts, poppler, debian-jessie

I have a strange issue where I don't even know how to pinpoint the issue… so I hope someone can help me figure this out

I have a node app that fills out pdf invoices. In my development environment (Mac OS) this works fine. When I dockerize my node app, using debian:jessie as base image, the € sign in my pdf form is rendered as fi ligature instead of €.

I am using the same font in the docker image that works on my mac (adobe garamond)

EDIT: this happens regardless of the font.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405902/how-to-set-the-locale-inside-a-docker-container ?

Comment: @200OK No, I have the following added to my docker but to no avail:


`RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y locales

RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    echo 'LANG="en_US.UTF-8"'>/etc/default/locale && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
    update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8`