# Date format yyyy-MM-dd Docker iis

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I have a problem with the Docker on which the iis server is installed.
Unfortunately, the date in my program is set in the format "MM / dd / yyyy" and I want it to be in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"
How to set the Dockerfile so that the date is in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"

[image]

[image: get-culture my Docker]

[image: The date the program displays]

Comment: I may be wrong, but It does not seem to be a docker related question. How do you get the date within your application ?

Comment: No. I need to know how to set a culture to get the date in the appropriate format "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: You want to know how to set locales ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405902/how-to-set-the-locale-inside-a-ubuntu-docker-container for linux systems, don't knowho wto do on Windows though. But this is not really Docker related. You could consider the scenario where you install an English OS from a USB key you would have  to do the same thing

Comment: I solved my problem.
It turned out that one of javascrip was formatting the date in a way that did not suit me.
thank you very much