# Python default locale (unsupported locale setting)

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, locale, setlocale

This seems like a weird problem, and it's causing my some heartburn, because i'm using a library that stashes the current locale, and tries to set it back to what it stashed.

```
$ docker run --rm -it python:3.6 bash
root@bcee8785c2e1:/# locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

```
root@bcee8785c2e1:/# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

```
root@bcee8785c2e1:/# python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jul 13 2019, 14:51:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import locale
>>> curr = locale.getlocale()
>>> curr
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, curr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/locale.py", line 598, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
>>>
```

I'm not sure why `getlocale` is returning `en_US`? It's not anywhere in my environment vars (and I'm not sure where else it could be in my shell?).

In any case, I can't `setlocale` with the value from `getlocale`, which seems weird to me.

Does anyone have any guidance here?

Much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think C.UTF-8 is a valid locale. C (synonym POSIX) is and is intended to be strictly a byte=char fall back [On phone so can't check]

Comment: It's a bit more complicated  Followup of above comment in answer below

Answer (score 1):

For the first part: Does it matter? As far I know, I never see differences until you call `setlocale()`, so we are on the second part:

You should use:

```
import locale
curr = locale.getdefaultlocale()
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, curr)
```

so `getdefaultlocale()` and not just `getlocale()`.  I also do not fully understand the reason to have both.  Is it possible that it is a Python bug that fail to recognize `C.xxx`.

Comment: It's crazy, same result : ('en_US', 'UTF-8') ... and same error...

Comment: But it doesn't crash. Note: I'm not sure if there are testable differences (with outputs), of just `C.utf-8` includes `en-US.utf-8`. [Python 3.7.3 here, with ` LC_ALL='C.utf8' python3 /tmp/b.py`]

Comment: Well whether the bug is python, debian, docker or libc is arguable. C.UTF-8 sure is a bug-magnet — see my answer below, particularly the Haskell and Redhat bug-reports.

Comment: @Rusi: but your answer is not an answer. `C.UTF-8` may be bad (but I looked the std and it should be correct, also because the two parts are different: one about how program should prepare things [user dependent], the second how to display [terminal dependent]. But the problem here is that the OP used the wrong function: he asked a string for locale which cannot be used to set locale. The string is an interpretation of locale string (useful for other purpose), but it is not a system locale, so it cannot be used safely. `C.UTF-8` is one case, but there are much more [locale semantic is complex]

Answer (score 1):

## C.UTF-8 — A recent non-portable debianism

The *intention* of C.UTF-8 is good but the *implementation* not quite yet. For now avoid till it stabilizes.

### Some discussion of context

A [redhat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=902094) discussion around including it. Which means it's not quite there (at time of writing at least). Note particularly, Nick Coghlan, a core python-dev, suggests that python doesn't get locales right in some contexts like this one.

A [haskell](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/856) discussion showing that portable cross-platform stuff — in this case haskell-stack but by implication also docker — becomes harder and less reliable with C.UTF-8 usage.

### The Intention

[Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/%3Ca%20href=%22bugreport.cgi?bug=636086%22%3E636086%3C/a%3E) ([also](https://web.open-infrastructure.net/software/locales-c.utf-8/)) initiated C.UTF-8 and the intention is correct.

Today's Linux systems are intensively localized — a slew of locales, fine-grained choice of LC_* choices etc etc. But all this is not on by default: if the locale system is broken the system is broken. The reason a broken locale-system is not as drastic in effects as say a broken kernel or fstab or grub etc is...

### The C locale

The [C locale](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36823/glmar.html) (synonym POSIX) is guaranteed to always be available as a fallback if other things break. So for example you won't see localized errors but English — not mojibake or empty rectangles or question-marks!

By and large you get these kind of [warnings](https://askubuntu.com/q/162391/358822) *not errors* and otherwise things keep working.

But C = POSIX implies the legacy ASCII not [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) — an undesired side-effect of legacy.

Towards making that legacy less and less necessary even as a fallback, Debian introduced the always available C.UTF-8 locale.

The catch? It's always available...

### Only in Debian

Which means *recent* Debian, derivatives like Ubuntu also recent. But not (yet) other systems.

In short C.UTF-8 is not universal, not portable, fragile and therefore avoidable... at least for now, at least on client-server, virtualized (containerized) etc systems like docker. The....

### Practical Upshot

You need to **explicitly** install old-fashioned locales like en_US.UTF-8. (People wanting a reasonable international English locale and not wanting en_US may wish to check out [en_DK.UTF-8](http://www.ivoras.net/blog/tree/2010-12-20.the-wonderful-en_dk-locale.html)).

Yeah that involves some amount of

## Getting your hands dirty

Here is a collection of references on docker oriented locale setup

- [Docker not quite a desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581458/how-to-configure-locales-to-unicode-in-a-docker-ubuntu-14-04-container/582197)
- [Various suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405902/how-to-set-the-locale-inside-a-debian-ubuntu-docker-container)
- [Debian](https://serverfault.com/a/662037/554579)
- [Locales: Ubuntu vs Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247019/323121)

I don't approve of one anti-pattern that repeats in the above but
It's going too far afield (from this question) to expand on this, so in v short:

Setting locale should usually **only** involve setting `LANG`.  Setting `LC_ALL` ,  especially along with `LANG` is a no-no.

From [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale#Configuration)

> ⚠️      **WARNING**
>
> Using LC_ALL is strongly discouraged as it overrides everything. Please use it only when testing and never set it in a startup file.

Comment: `en_DK` Is a crazy aberration which would perhaps be defensible if *it* was available everywhere by default; but, alas, it is not. Also IIRC it has less than ideal values for dates and currency. Perhaps see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62316/why-is-there-no-euro-english-locale

Comment: @tripleee I've weakened the en_DK reference. Can remove it if you prefer (It's hardly relevant to the q or a!)