# How to set encoding on docker image generated by Spring boot build-image maven plugin

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I've a project with spring boot 2.5.1

When I create the docker image with the following command

```
mvn -B spring-boot:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=franco -DskipTests
```

and then i run it with
docker run franco

I see the following error

```
2021-06-25 10:23:11.173 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.FileEncodingApplicationListener  : System property 'file.encoding' is currently 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'. It should be 'UTF-8' (as defined in 'spring.mandatoryFileEncoding').
2021-06-25 10:23:11.177 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.FileEncodingApplicationListener  : Environment variable LANG is 'null'. You could use a locale setting that matches encoding='UTF-8'.
2021-06-25 10:23:11.178 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.FileEncodingApplicationListener  : Environment variable LC_ALL is 'null'. You could use a locale setting that matches encoding='UTF-8'.
2021-06-25 10:23:11.397 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

How can i set this env variable using the build-image goal?

Comment: it depends on the docker image/OS ... [here exemplary for debian/ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28405902/592355)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following in order to set the encoding

```
docker run -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" <image_name>
```