# File.list()*.exists() not true for files with umlauts

Tags: java, groovy, locale

Im facing a problem with umlauts in groovy/java on a ubuntu server.

This groovy code return for exists() false for files with umlauts:

```
def f1 = new File('/var/lib/jenkins/test/')
def files = [:]
f1.listFiles().each {
  files.put(it.name, it.getAbsoluteFile().exists())
}
println files
println 'file.encoding:' + System.getProperty('file.encoding')
```

Results in:

```
Verderblichkeit.docx:true
Gefa��hrlichkeit.docx:false
file.encoding:"iso-8859-1"
```

So it return false for a file it found itself with listFile(). That is wrong.

ls -al in the drirectory:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 jenkins jenkins   4096 Jan  5 18:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 66 jenkins jenkins  12288 Jan  5 18:16 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  98035 Jan  5 18:16 Gefährlichkeit.docx
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins 277515 Jan  5 18:17 Verderblichkeit.docx
```

In linux I can copy or mv or rename the files and see the umlauts.

Environment:

- Version of Java: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)

Note: The original problem is getting the file path from a database. The file can be found and served throug nginx but in the java app (grails with groovy files) I get a false result for File.exists()

What can I do?

I tried setting UTF-8 as file.encoding by setting this in the application environment or by -D param on start. I searched the web but didn't find a solution.

Comment: Interestingly, if you copied and pasted from your terminal, Gefährlichkeit.docx has its a umlaut as two separate characters, which can happen sometimes. What, in the terminal, is the output of `ls *rlichkeit.docx`?

Comment: What if you print name with and without getAbsoluteFile()? 2 bytes means utf-8 but if you still see 2 bytes in terminal - it's wrong.

Comment: why do you need to check for existence of files, which are returned by file iterating methods? if files are returned, they DO exist by definition...

Comment: Thanks for your replies. We use UTF-8 in our dev env and in the database. The app runs in a tomcat directly on a server and in a container. g00se: With ls the file name is printed correct like in the ls -al above as 'Gefährlichkeit.docx'. daggett: The file name inside the app is always printed wrong like above as 'Gefa��hrlichkeit.docx'. injecteer: This is only code showing the core of the problem. The app gets the file name from the database as 'Gefährlichkeit.docx' and java can't find the file then.

Comment: @g00se: With ls the file name is printed correct like in the ls -al above as 'Gefährlichkeit.docx'.

Comment: @daggett: The file name inside the app is always printed wrong like above as 'Gefa��hrlichkeit.docx'.

Comment: @injecteer: This is only code showing the core of the problem. The app gets the file name from the database as 'Gefährlichkeit.docx' and java can't find the file then.

Comment: if the file name comes from the DB, it should be a URI instead!

Comment: Your problem is being caused by Unicode composition. See [java.text.Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Normalizer.html) Perhaps more from me on this later

Comment: Thanks for your replies. So far I think I can fix the problem by setting sun.jnu.encoding to 'UTF-8' on application startup. In the dev env it works by setting it in the grails 4 app via build.gradle in the bootRun section. I try it now in the tomcat servers and come back later.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

The problem occured in different environments:

1. development env: grails 4 application startet with gradle bootRun
2. CI-stage with a tomcat 9 server
3. production env: tomcat running in a docker container

**Short answer:**
The problem was the wrong settings for sun.jnu.encoding. Solution was to set it in the correct way for each env.

**Long answer:**
We had to set the java system property 'sun.jnu.encoding' in the different envs :

### 1. dev env

Set system properties in the bootRun section in build.gradle:

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs(
        '-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8',
        '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8',
        ...)
}
```

### 2. tomcat 9 on server

Set system properties in setenv.sh in tomcat/bin:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 $JAVA_OPTS"
```

### 3. tomcat 9 in docker container in prod env

We used this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/28406007/14748724. We need to rebuild the container image.

Finally we had to set this in the docker-compose.yaml file:

```
tomcat:
   environment:
      LC_ALL: 'en_US.UTF-8'
```

Before it was `LC_ALL: 'C'`, which was wrong.

*Note: Using the setenv.sh solution from env 2. **didn't** work in the container!*

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer as such, but it allows me to show the problem with Unicode composition and file names. Let's create two files with the same name:

```
goose@t410:/tmp$ touch $(echo -e '\x61\xCC\x88.txt')
goose@t410:/tmp$ touch $(echo -e '\xC3\xA4.txt')
goose@t410:/tmp$ ls *.txt
ä.txt  ä.txt
```

What!? Hang on, this is a trick isn't it? They are really the same file? Here's proof they are different:

```
goose@t410:/tmp$ ls -i *.txt
```

131467 ä.txt  131527 ä.txt

Comment: You are right like I can see. We solved this problem by setting the system properties and locales in the way the env s needed. I posted an answer.

Comment: I think it can get even weirder. It might be possible to have a file called ä.txt with its name encoded as, say, ISO-8859-1 and have its name read identically if you have more than one locale installed. I say "I think" as I haven't tested this as I don't want to mess with my en_GB.UTF-8 locale. But I *know* I could make a file with that name in ISO-8859-1. My doubt is only whether it would also read correctly