# How to get charset of Process in Java?

Tags: java

`Charset.defaultCharset()` and `file.encoding` is JVM's charset, **not** charset of **OS, console and terminal**.

Now I create a `Process` to run a program, and use `process.getInputSteam()` to read the output, how to find the correct charset for the process (`sun.jnu.encoding` is right but it seems not general)?

Comment: Check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066845/what-exactly-is-sun-jnu-encoding

Answer (score 2):

From *Java 17* onwards, there is a method in *Process* class named `inputStream`.

The source code taken from *Process.java*:

```
public final BufferedReader inputReader() {
    return inputReader(CharsetHolder.nativeCharset());
}
```

The `nativeCharset` is obtained from System property "**native.encoding**".

This property was introduced in Java 17. This is probably what you want.

Reference: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8266075

Comment: Be aware this may change in Java 18, when most character-encoding defaults will change to UTF-8 across all platforms. See [*JEP 400: UTF-8 by Default*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/400).